# How do I change the distance from the top till the text in a column?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a HTML site where I need to make between 3 vertical columns, one horizontal header, and one footer. But when I'm writing something in the `header/footer`, the text won't fit in the column.

I have made an HTML document, with a stylesheet.css.

```css
.title{
border-radius: 8px;
border-collapse: collapse;
border: 2px solid black;
float: left;
height: 15px;
padding-top:5px;
padding-bottom: 33px;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-top: 5px;
width: 95%;
}
```

```html
<div class="rowTop">
  <div class="columnTop">
    <div class="title">
      <h2>Header</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I expect that the distance from the top to the text needs to get smaller, but when I change the `px`, they won't get smaller than this.

Comment: It is hard to determine what you are actually asking for. Maybe you could clarify a little. You referenced trying to change px to make smaller. On what, exactly?

Comment: Explaining this with my English is not easy, so here is a screenshot of what i'm trying to say - https://ibb.co/fGST4vw the "footer" and the" header" text need to get a little bit higher, so it would be perfect in the middle of the column.

Comment: Your CSS has no selector, please fix that.

Comment: What you are looking for is the well know 'MDN holy grail' CSS webpage layout. Here is a good example [Codepen - MDN Holy Grail Flexbox Layout](https://codepen.io/fskirschbaum/pen/LVPeJb). Works like a charm and, wadda you know, responsive...

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to reference your class names in your style sheet

```css
.rowTop{
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid black;
  float: left;
  height: 15px;
  padding-top:5px;
  padding-bottom: 33px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 95%;
}
```

```html
<div class="rowTop">
  <div class="columnTop">
    <div class="title">
      <h2>Header</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but first off your HTML is missing a terminating `div`:

```
<div class="rowTop">
  <div class="columnTop">
    <div class="title">
      <h2>Header</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and your CSS has no selector:

```
.CSS-selector-here {
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid black;
  float: left;
  height: 15px;
  padding-top:5px;
  padding-bottom: 33px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 95%;
}
```

For a simple header, footer, three-column layout, I would recommend trying to understand [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox). A simple layout might look something like:

```css
div {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.header, .footer {
  width: 90%;
  height: 15vh;
}

.flex-container {
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex-child {
  width: 30%;
  height: 85vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-child">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-child">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-child">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>
```